# What is P(C1 | B4) ? 5 coins tossed probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Given: The probability of getting head for each coin
p1 = 0, p2 = 1/4, p3 = 1/2, p4 = 3/4, p5 =1

The question is

> Suppose we toss the selected coin four times. Find p(Ci | B4) for each
> i = 1, . . . , 5. Here B4 means that the first head is obtained on the
> fourth toss.

What I have already calculated for other problems of this question:
P(Get Head when a coin is tossed)= P(H)

```
P(H) = 1/2
P(C1|H) = 0, P(C2|H) = 1/10 , P(C3|H) = 1/5 , P(C4|H) = 3/10, P(C5|H) = 2/5
P(H2 | H1 ) = 3/4
```

Because of it`s head only at fourth try. I thought I need to use Geometric Distribution (P(x) = q^x-1 * p).

I calculated it and its `P(B4) = 1/16`. Here I use P(H) in the `p.

Then going back to original problem: P(C1 | B4) = P(C1 ∩ B4)/P(B4)

Then can you please tell me what P(C1 U B4) is?

Comment: You mean $P(C_1 \color{red} \cap B_4)$? Or do you mean $P(C_1 \cup B_4)=P(C_1)+P(B_4)-P(C_1  \cap B_4)$?

Comment: I assume it`s (C1∩B4) as I use the formula for conditional probability.  Am i even doing correctly?